# Why is this basic SpaCy example not working?

Tags: python, nlp, conda, spacy

I'm testing [this basic example](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity) from the SpaCy docs and getting some strange results.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
tokens = nlp(u'dog cat banana')

for token1 in tokens:
    for token2 in tokens:
        print(token1.text, token2.text, token1.similarity(token2))
```

My setup:

- MacBook Pro
- macOS 10.13.4
- Conda 4.5.9
- Python 3.5.5
- SpaCy 2.0.12

Expected results:

```
dog dog 1.0
dog cat 0.80168545
dog banana 0.24327646
cat dog 0.80168545
cat cat 1.0
cat banana 0.2815437
banana dog 0.24327646
banana cat 0.2815437
banana banana 1.0
```

My Results:

```
dog dog 1.0
dog cat 0.0
dog banana 0.0
cat dog 0.0
cat cat 1.0
cat banana -0.0446812
banana dog -7.82874e+17
banana cat -8.24222e+17
banana banana 1.0
```

I've tried uninstalling & re-installing SpaCy and all of the various models and even SpaCy itself. I've also tried an even simpler example:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
cat = nlp(u'cat')
dog = nlp(u'dog')
print(cat.similarity(dog)) # 0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new Conda environment that uses Python 3.7 rather than 3.6. I'm now seeing the same results that the demo in the SpaCy docs produces.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this problem is caused by an issue with a particular version of numpy. Upgrading numpy usually helps – or, in your case, the new environment likely installed a more recent version that doesn't have this problem.